# iOS screen with multiple collectionView Controllers invokes cellForItemAtIndexPath incorrectly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

**Situation**

My iOS phone app has 2 UICollectionViews on one screen.  So I have distinct subclasses for each logical view.

- AAACollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
- AAACollectionView : UICollectionView
- BBBCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
- BBBCollectionView : UICollectionView

Good news is that AAACollectionViewController.numberOfItemsInSection gets invoked on the correct View and BBBCollectionViewController.numberOfItemsInSection gets invoked on the correct view.  Also, the correct cellForItemAtIndexPath is invoked correctly.

AAA has 2 cells and BBB has 12 cells.

**Problem**

However, BBB.cellForItemAtIndexPath is only invoked 2 times.

This is true even if I add the child controllers in a different order:

```
parent.addChildViewController(AAA)
parent.addChildViewController(BBB)
```

or

```
parent.addChildViewController(BBB)
parent.addChildViewController(AAA)
```

Also if AAA has 3 cells, then BBB.cellForItemAtIndexPath is invoked 3 times.

Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I accidentally shared the same UICollectionViewFlowLayout object with both views.  The symptom of the problem is very odd, in that several aspects worked fine.

After using separate flow objects the UI performs as expected.